# Android GCM message not received?

Tags: java, android

I am working with `Google App Engine` And I want to send `Push Notification` to other Devices.I can send message locally but my problem is that when I live my android app to play store .its stop working I can't received message from Gcm. I use server key which is generated from Developer console. I get error `code 204`

my Manifest permissions are

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: Which GCM is it, the old (deprecated) or new one which uses Google Play services? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919247/difference-between-deprecated-gcm-and-new-gcm-which-uses-google-play-service

Comment: What protocol is used on the backend server, HTTP or XMPP? Did you check that the Google Cloud server returned no error for the request?

Comment: have you added Sha1 key of your keystore in http://console.developers.google.com app you have created

Comment: i use new Gcm compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'